# Grails - Extending an instance

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I've been working with Grails for a couple months now and I've stumbled upon something...

So I have a small application with Spring Security installed and made users etc.

Thank you all in advance

**-------EDIT--------**

To make the question more simple and straight forward, forget the class names.

```
class ABC extends XYZ{...}

class XYZ{...}
```

Question: Can multiple objects of XYZ extend the same object of ABC? **So if I already have object ABC1 that extends XYZ1, can I create XYZ2 and have it extend ABC1 as well?

Comment: some objects extending another object? I don't get it. Or you are talking about some Class extends another?

Comment: I don't get it either. first, your `ABC` is extending `XYZ` and then you want multiple `XYZ` to extend `ABC`? no, not possible. you can't have circular inheritance ...

Comment: Jinzhao: ABC domain class, an ABC object/an instance of ABC in grails is the same thing is it not? 
herom: No, I'm saying can instances XYZ1, XYZ2, XYZ3 extend ABC1, so not circular of course

Comment: Can you please make the question more clear. As I read it. You're asking if instances can extends one another while only classes can be extended. It doesn't make any sense so you'll get people guessing what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that a user should have a group. Depending on your model they could have one or more groups. So my suggestion:

```
class Group {
  String name
}
```

Association with `User`:

```
class User {
  Group userGroup
}
```

or

```
class User {
  static hasMany = [groups: Group]
}
```

In the way that you created your classes it seems that a **group is a user** and I think that's not what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Maybe Group was a bad example..but lets say it was an Employer. I'm aware of this workaround but I'm looking for, and prefer a solution where I can(if possible) have an Employer being accessible only to the set of Users who manage this Employer profile. Thank you though Sérgio.

Comment: In this case my example applies. You have the user, and the user have one or many Employer profiles that he can change the data. You can create a Filter that return access denied if some user try to access the controller action of a Employer that he don't have access.

Comment: Thank you I will take a look at that, I've updated the question so maybe it's more clear now.

Comment: After looking around some more and giving it some thought, it seems like this would be the best way to solve my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may need [Hierarchical Roles](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/14%20Hierarchical%20Roles.html) instead of a group of users to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your attempt to answer my question...I've reworded it since it was more of a general question. The class names made it misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i might be missing your point, but it sounds like you're looking for row-level (or instance-level) access control.  For example it seems like you want only certain users (those within a certain group) to be able to access (view, edit, etc) an object (e.g. that same group object).

If that's your intent, then I'd recommend looking at the shiro plugin -- it does instance-level ACL better than Spring Secuity, in my opinion.

http://grails.org/plugin/shiro

There's also a new plugin that integrates shiro ACL through Spring Security.  Haven't tested it out myself but looks like it might be the way to go if you've already integrated Spring Security into your app.

http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-shiro

Comment: Thank you for your attempt to answer my question...I've reworded it since it was more of a general question. The class names made it misleading.